# Python: Keep track of which dictionary paths were accessed

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a huge python dictionary (few gigs when written to a JSON). Before writing the dictionary to the disk, there are a bunch of routines that take this dictionary and use information in certain paths (legacy code).

I'd like to keep track of which paths are accessed / used. One way is to go through this legacy code and I am looking for a way that avoids this.

I can instrument the code before calling into these legacy routines. Is there anything I can do that can result in tracking/logging the paths in the huge dictionary that are being accessed.

e.g.

```
{

  "a": {
      "b": {
            "c": "d"
       }
  }
  "e": {
      "f": {
            "g": "h"
       }
  }
```

Lets say the legacy code accessed the key "g", I need to log the path (e:f:g). I'd like to do this without touching/modifying the legacy code.

Comment: Subclass the `dict` type and overwrite `__getitem__`.

Comment: @KlausD. Overriding `__getitem__` only works if you access your dict with `[]`. Values retrieved with `get()` or `pop()` won't be counted as accessed, because these methods are not using `__getitem__.

Comment: @kszl: on python 3.6.9 it works